# Issue with gltf animation

Tags: reactjs, three.js, gltf

I'm currently working on a website using React and Three.js that involves rendering 3D models. I'm using a 3D model obtained from [here (sketchfab)](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/robot-playground-59fc99d8dcb146f3a6c16dbbcc4680da) and converted it into a JSX file using gltfjsx.

The model loads successfully, and I managed to incorporate the animations. However, I'm experiencing issues with the animation, textures, and lighting. The model does not look as intended, and I'm struggling to find a solution.

I have tried various approaches, including adjusting the lighting and linking the texture files correctly, but so far, nothing has resolved the issues.

[With no light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9ryB.png)

[With Light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGrIi.png)

The differences in appearance between the two versions suggest that there might be an issue with the lighting setup or the texture assignment.

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm currently using:

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import React, { Suspense, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Canvas, useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls, useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";

const ModelComponent = () => {
  const model = useGLTF("./path/to/model.gltf");
  const groupRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Play animations when the model is loaded
    model.animations.forEach((animation) => {
      model.scene.animations.push(animation);
    });
    groupRef.current.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(groupRef.current);
    const action = groupRef.current.mixer.clipAction(model.animations[0]);
    action.play();
  }, [model]);

  useFrame((_, delta) => {
    groupRef.current.mixer?.update(delta);
  });

  return (
    <group ref={groupRef}>
      <primitive object={model.scene} />
    </group>
  );
};

const MyCanvas = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas>
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        <OrbitControls />
        {/* Lighting setup */}
   
        <ModelComponent />
      </Suspense>
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default MyCanvas;
```

I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve these animation, texture, and lighting issues. Any insights, suggestions, or possible solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem for gltf model or lighting.
Three js mesh does not emit light on its own, achieving a glowing effect requires post-processing. This can be done using techniques such as post-processing shaders.

You need to add post progressing, including bloom effect, FXAA, etc.

Official example:

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=bloom#webgl_postprocessing_unreal_bloom_selective
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_unreal_bloom.html
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_fxaa.html

There is a package for using postprocessing in react.

```
npm install @react-three/postprocessing
```

https://github.com/pmndrs/react-postprocessing

You need to set up and identify which mesh is a bloom mesh.

https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-postprocessing/effects/bloom

Codesandbox sample:

https://codesandbox.io/s/r9ujf